# How do you modify a resource in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio

I've just begun working in Android Studio and after adding a new resource, I can't find where to modify it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a strings values list. You can see the file from your Project (Click on the Project toolbar on the upper left of your Android Studio). Then select Android from the dropdown list. Now select `App (Or your module name) -> res -> values`. You can see a file with `strings.xml` name. All your string is inside that file. Don't forget to check the same file name but with different flag icon.

All of your resource file is also inside the `App -> res -> values` folder.